# Can you suffocate a creature using Create Water?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic

Can a cleric with [Create Water](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/createWater.htm) conjure water inside a corporeal creature's lung (or appropriate respiratory system) to [suffocate](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm#suffocation) him? If not, can he [drown](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm#drowning) the creature by conjuring water around him?

Comment: @Samuraisoulification Stack Exchange isn't a good fit for open discussion questions; you're basically asking for any creative use of the spell that we can think of. That means every answer is equally correct and it invites debate and discussion (like the "but what about?" comment you gave to the answer below), which isn't what Stack Exchange is for. You would have more success with this question in a standard RPG forum. Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site.

Comment: @Samuraisoulification I edited the question to be objective, assuming you have intended that way. Please check the revision, and feel free to accept or decline it based on whether the edit fits your purpose. By the way, you don't have to worry about purifying the water, since SRD specifically says _The water created by this spell is just like clean rain water, and it doesn’t go bad as the food does._

Answer (score 19):

The specific description of the Create Water spell on page 215 of the Player's Handbook says:

> Water can be created in an area as small as will actually contain the liquid, or in an area three times as large

and

> *Note:* Conjuration spells can't create substances or objects within a creature.

Thus you couldn't create the water directly inside the creature, both because it is a creature, and because it's mouth would (most probably) be too small to contain the entire  volume created.

This does not stop you from conjuring the water in an appropriately inanimate container and then forcing it into the creature.

Answer (score 0):

No to the first, can't create it within the creature.
As to the second, if you could drown a creature by creating sufficient water around them... that depends on where we are and how much water*.

If standing in relatively flat land, creating the water over the head would just lead to the equivalent to the "Ice Bucket Challenge" or the ritual pouring of water over a coach's head at the end of a sports game. You could argue for some surprise value, but gravity keeps it from staying at nose level for too long.

At 8 gallons per cubic foot, you'd need to be around 144th level to cover someone in a sarcophagus with a foot of water. But what about their head? At 4th level you could cover someone's head reliably enough. They'd have to be unable to remove their head from said water. This wouldn't be terribly doable in combat, and if the goal is SOLELY to kill, it's not terribly effective.

However, as an execution ritual it works fine. It also works well for a magical murderer. Add in a custom spell (or side-effect of another spell) to freeze water, and you've got yourself a D&D take on the old "ice bullet" mystery!

* = And, of course, depends on your GM. If your GM says that your Half-Orc who's wrestled a kobold can put his hand over the kobold's mouth and use Create Water to suffocate/aid in suffocating the critter, that makes sense... but it also makes sense if your GM says "No, that's not the point of the spell so it just doesn't work that way."